# React, image modal (ant-design) component is not rendering the second time

Tags: reactjs, react-native, antd, react-props

I am using ant-design as design library in my react project. I created an Image modal component for showing an image.

```
class ImageModal extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super();
    this.state  = {
        showModal : props.showImage
    }
}

closeModal = (e) => {
    this.setState({ showModal : false })
}

render() {
    return (
        <Modal id='lajeet__modal' centered closable={true} visible={this.state.showModal} footer={null} width={900} height={700} 
            onCancel={(e) => this.closeModal(e)} onHide={this.close}>
            <ImageInModal>
                <img src={this.props.imageSrc} width={850} height={700} marginTop={50}></img>
            </ImageInModal>
        </Modal>
    )
}
```

}

export default ImageModal;

On click, of the below button, I am opening the Image Modal component

```
{ !this.isStartingSession ? <FormButton type="ghost" onClick={(e) => this.setShowImageStateAndUrl(e, true, 'https://picsum.photos/800')}>View Check Out Image</FormButton> : '' }
```

I am calling this component in some other component as,

```
{ this.state.checkInAndOutImageUrl ? <ImageModal showImage={this.state.showImage} imageSrc={this.state.checkInAndOutImageUrl}></ImageModal> : ''}
```

The function which I am using for setting the state,

```
setShowImageStateAndUrl = (event, value, imageSrc) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState({checkInAndOutImageUrl : imageSrc});
    this.setState({showImage : value});
}
```

Comment: Can you share a codesandbox for your problem ?

Answer (score 0):

the provided sample code is not so clear. but i think your app will be fixed by the following code:

```
 { this.state.checkInAndOutImageUrl && this.state.showImage ? 
   <ImageModal showImage={this.state.showImage} imageSrc={this.state.checkInAndOutImageUrl}></ImageModal> 
    : 
    ''}
```